# Turn off raspberry pi headless mode

Tags: headless

My raspberry pi 4 is setup to work in headless mode and its working ok but I want to turnoff headless mode and make it working normally by connecting it to monitor and keyboard.

Is it possible now and if yes then what steps I need to follow?

Comment: How did you "turn ON headless *mode*" - by not attaching a keyboard and screen - therefore, it seems obvious to turn OFF headless *mode*, one does the opposite

Comment: Do you mean if I attach monitor it will start in Desktop mode automatically?

Comment: No, but it won't be headless with a monitor attached - I think you are using incorrect terminology

Answer (score 1):

If by "headless mode" you mean there's no GUI desktop, and by "working normally" you mean there is a GUI desktop, this is done by setting the systemd boot target:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

If you installed the "lite" version of RpiOS, however, there will be no GUI installed, so you will just get a console prompt.  If you installed the full version, it should already boot to a GUI by default, although this won't be apparent if you don't have a monitor attached.

Comment: But what about the resolution. Don't we have to set it according to the monitor?

Comment: Only if there's a problem, in which case you have another, more specific question that needs to include details about the monitor.  Please only do that if there is a problem, and put it in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as headless mode.

Boot mode is setup in `raspi-config`.

If your Pi is set to boot to **Desktop** (as most of mine are) you can use it headlessly.

If a monitor is attached you can use the GUI.

If you boot to **Console** mode you can start GUI with `startx`.

If you want to use GUI remotely (with VNC) you should set to boot to **Desktop** and should set VNC resolution in `raspi-config`.